# Node.js SSL error - no ciphers available

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I was able to upload files to dropbox using request.js module. I was trying to upload file using pure Node.js https.request() and request.write(). As dropbox needs https connection, I am using https.request(). But I am receiving error while using them(second code):

When secureProtocol is SSLv2_method:

```
Problem with request: 3074844416:error:140650B5:SSL routines:CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers available:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s2_clnt.c:562:
```

After I change secureProtocol to SSLv3_method I receive error:

```
Problem with request: write EPROTO 3074537216:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:348:
```

I was not able to install kerberos. Could this be the problem ?

Here are my code:

Using request.js module:
At last few lines I am piping the readable stream to request.put().

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    express = require('express'),
    request = require('request'),
    url = require('url'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    fs = require('fs');
    app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

var APP_KEY = 'opmdwo6kpnyswfp';
var APP_SECRET = 'an6vl11lc9rp51e';

function generateCSRFToken() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(18).toString('base64')
        .replace(/\//g,'-').replace(/\+/g,'_');
}

function generateRedirectURI(req) {
    return url.format({
        protocol: req.protocol,
        host: req.headers.host,
        pathname: app.path() + '/callback'
    });
}

function getFileSize(fileName) {
    var stats = fs.statSync(fileName);
    var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];
    var fileSizeInMegaBytes = fileSizeInBytes / 1000000.0;
    return fileSizeInBytes;
}

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var csrfToken = generateCSRFToken();
    res.cookie('csrf',csrfToken);
    res.redirect(url.format({
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'www.dropbox.com',
        pathname: '1/oauth2/authorize',
        query: {
            client_id: APP_KEY,
            response_type: 'code',
            state: csrfToken,
            redirect_uri: generateRedirectURI(req)
        }
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
    if(req.query.error) {
        return res.send('ERROR ' + req.query.error + ': ' +
                req.query.error_description);
    }

    if(req.query.state !== req.cookies.csrf) {
        return res.status(401).send('CSRF token mismatch, possible' +
                'cross-site request forgery attempt.'
                );
    }

    request.post('https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token', {
        form: {
            code: req.query.code,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri: generateRedirectURI(req)
        },
        auth: {
            user: APP_KEY,
            pass: APP_SECRET
        }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);

            if(data.error)
                return res.send('ERROR: ' + data.error);

            var token = data.access_token;

            var fileName = "aai_success.pdf";
            var path = encodeURI("https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files_put/auto/" + fileName);

            fs.createReadStream(fileName).pipe(request.put(path, {
                headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token },
                'Content-Length': getFileSize(fileName)
                }, function(error, response, body) {
                    console.log(response);
            }));
        });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Application is running on port 3000');
});
```

Using Node.js https.request()

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    https = require('https');
    express = require('express'),
    request = require('request'),
    url = require('url'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

var APP_KEY = 'opmdwo6kpnyswfp';
var APP_SECRET = 'an6vl11lc9rp51e';

function generateCSRFToken() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(18).toString('base64')
        .replace(/\//g,'-').replace(/\+/g,'_');
}

function generateRedirectURI(req) {
    return url.format({
        protocol: req.protocol,
        host: req.headers.host,
        pathname: app.path() + '/callback'
    });
}

function getFileSize(fileName) {
    var stats = fs.statSync(fileName);
    var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];
    var fileSizeInMegaBytes = fileSizeInBytes / 1000000.0;
    return fileSizeInBytes;
}

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var csrfToken = generateCSRFToken();
    res.cookie('csrf',csrfToken);
    res.redirect(url.format({
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'www.dropbox.com',
        pathname: '1/oauth2/authorize',
        query: {
            client_id: APP_KEY,
            response_type: 'code',
            state: csrfToken,
            redirect_uri: generateRedirectURI(req)
        }
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
    if(req.query.error) {
        return res.send('ERROR ' + req.query.error + ': ' +
                req.query.error_description);
    }

    if(req.query.state !== req.cookies.csrf) {
        return res.status(401).send('CSRF token mismatch, possible' +
                'cross-site request forgery attempt.'
                );
    }

    request.post('https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token', {
        form: {
            code: req.query.code,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri: generateRedirectURI(req)
        },
        auth: {
            user: APP_KEY,
            pass: APP_SECRET
        }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);

            if(data.error)
                return res.send('ERROR: ' + data.error);

            var token = data.access_token;
            console.log("Access token: " + token);

            var fileName = "aai_success.pdf";

            var options = {
                hostname: 'content.dropboxapi.com',
                port: 80,
                path: '/1/files_put/auto/test.txt',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'Content-Length': 2,
                    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
                },
                strictSSL: false,
                secureProtocol: 'SSLv3_method'
            };

            var rqst = https.request(options, function(res) {
                console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
                console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
                res.setEncoding('utf8');

                res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
                });
            });

            rqst.write('AB');
            rqst.end();

            rqst.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
            });
            /*
            var bts = 0;
            fs.createReadStream(fileName).on('data', function(chunk) {
                console.log("Got %d bytes from disk: ", chunk.length);
                bts += bts + chunk.length;
                var bytesSent = rqst.write(chunk);
                console.log('Bytes sent: ' + bytesSent);
            });

            if(bts == 240519)
                rqst.end();
            */
        });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Application is running on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Dropbox does neither support SSL 2.0 nor SSL 3.0 because both are insecure. Use TLS.

Comment: You mean like this: secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method'

Comment: If this is the proper syntax then yes.

Comment: But it is mentioned on site that they accept only SSL connections.

Comment: I used TLS, but error of wrong version number persists.

Comment: "..they accept only SSL connections" - TLS is just another word for SSL. TLS 1.0 is actually SSL 3.1.

Comment: As I mentioned, I used it, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain a server certificate. You can self sign one for development using openssl (assuming you're on Linux) or you can obtain temporarily free ones. You also have the option to buy one from a certificate authority. Once you obtain a certificate look at the node.js docs under HTTPS or look at TLS (recommended) you can use their examples verbatim to setup SSL. https://nodejs.org/api/https.html

https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html

Comment: But why I am able to successfully upload file using request.js's request.put() method. It doesn't asks me for certificate

Comment: You'll need a certificate for SSL.

Comment: I get that there are free certificates available for development purposes. But is it like something that request.js handles for me. I think it is unlikely.

Comment: @user101285 assuming your app keys are legitimate. Please go right now to drop box  and request a new APP key. You have compromised the secrecy of those keys.

Comment: Thanks. But can you tell me how am I able to successfully upload files using request.js without a SSL certificate

Comment: @user101285 request will automatically follow http redirects so it'll upgrade the connection to HTTPS by establishing a tunnel/socket which is secure. The HTTPS server requires certificates to start up and listen for secure  connections to your server. Request is handling the connection to drop box.

Comment: Trying self signed ssl certificate. Will post whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem.

Change the port number to 443 and
remove the Content-Type header in options variable.

Didn't need to use strictSSL and secureProtocol

Didn't need to use SSL certificate.